# Install app into jailbroken ios Root’s Applications folder

Tags: ios5, jailbreak

when i put myapp.app in ios5 root's Applications folder, but it can't work. 
why? but i find that cydia can work normally.

Answer (score 3):

1. In the main.m add `setuid(0);` and `setgid(0);`
2. Build the app normally.
3. Then copy and paste the executable inside the .app and rename it to
   anything you want, don't rename the original file.
4. Open the original executable file and delete its contents (the
   contents are now stored in the previously copied and renamed
   binary).
5. Add this bash script to the empty binary file from 4. :

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   dir=$(dirname "$0")
   exec "${dir}"/<COPIED FILE NAME> "$@"
   ```

   Springboard will run this file first because its the CFBundleExecutable, then this will launch the actual app's
   executable. This is done because SpringBoard would fail to directly launch the executable with root permissions
6. Open terminal and change the directory to the .app (ex. `cd
   /User/Me/Desktop/MyApp.app`)
7. `chmod` the original executable file to 0755 (ex. `chmod 0755
   MyCFBundleExecutable`) and the copied file to 6755 (ex. `chmod 6755
   CFBundleExecutableRoot`)
8. SSH the .app into /Applications on your device, respring and launch
   it (if its not launching then repeat set 7. but by SSHing into your device via terminal)